# Pattern to register metatypes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

### Introduction

I've got a library, which registers a bunch of metatypes, illustrated by this code:

---

*abstractfoobase.h*

```
namespace foo {
    enum FooState { OK, MAYBE };
    class AbstractFooBase : public QObject {...};
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(foo::FooState)
```

There is also a corresponding *abstractfoobase.cpp*, contents depending on what exactly is implemented in base class.

---

*foousingclass.h:*

```
namespace foo {

    class FooUsingClass : public AbstractFooBase {...};
}
```

Again there is corresponding *foousingclass.cpp*, which has method implementations etc.

---

Now, that `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` enables the type for Qt template classes and `QVariant`. To enable using the type in queued signals and such, there also needs to be a corresponding call:

```
qRegisterMetaType<foo::FooState>();
```

### Question

What is(are) the good place(s) to put the `qRegisterMetaType` call? I obviously don't want any expllicit initialization call from application code. The registrations must have happened after doing a `foo::FooUsingClass *f = new foo::FooUsingClass();`.

In Java I'd put this kind of code in a static initialization block. I can see several ways to do this in C++ too, but none of them seem particularily nice. For example, simply putting these to `AbstractFooBase` constructor will cause the registrations being called every time a subclass instance is created, which may be undesired overhead. So those who have done this, where did you put the `qRegisterMetaType` calls?

Comment: I would include that headers in the main.cpp and call it from `main()`.

Comment: @bkausbk Well, this question has the explicit requirement, that any extra init calls must not be needed, all must happen behind the scenes (from the point of view of the application code).

Comment: @hyde You can also create a static instance of an initialization class that will register meta-type upon its construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can imagine something as following:

in abstractfoobase.cpp:

```
namespace foo {

/// Initializer
class FooStateInit {
public:
    FooStateInit() {
        qRegisterMetaType<foo::FooState>();
    }
};
static FooStateInit fooStateInit;

} // namespace foo
```

Comment: Works for me, just missing a `;` after the class declaration.

Answer (score 9):

I've recently discovered a simple solution, which works with static libraries as well.

It exploits the fact that `qMetaTypeId<>()` is used throughout Qt's meta type system. So, with an explicit template instantiation, we can enforce linkage to *abstractfoobase.cpp* (otherwise the linker might decide not to if there are no referenced symbols) and ensure that the type is registered statically at program startup:

*abstractfoobase.h*

```
#include <QMetaType>

namespace foo {
    enum FooState { OK, MAYBE };
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(foo::FooState)

extern template int qMetaTypeId<foo::FooState>();
```

*abstractfoobase.cpp*

```
static const int kFooStateMetaTypeId = qRegisterMetaType<foo::FooState>();

template int qMetaTypeId<foo::FooState>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If your type will be instantiated frequently, you could use a function static initialization in the constructor:

```
struct OftenInstantiatedDataType
{
    OftenInstantiatedDataType()
    {
        static const int reg = qRegisterMetaType<OftenInstantiatedDataType>();
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(OftenInstantiatedDataType);
```

Pros:

- Lazy registration - will only be called if your type is instantiated at all
- Single registration - will only be called once, no matter how often your type is instantiated

Cons:

- Makes executable larger

Answer (score 1):

In the few apps I created I used to simply register them in `main()`-like function that defines the application's startup. Of course, that separates the registration from the .cpp/.h file, but in turn it guarantees that I will not fall into some name-collisions (I see all names/types in one place) and also guarantees that the regs are done exactly one single time: app startup ;)

But, that's not a.. 'handy' way.. if anyone has better way, I'd like to see it too.